# lock the position of an nswindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

is it posible to lock the position of an nswindow? I'm not asking for setIgnoresMouseEvents. I need to prevent the user from moving the window, but he should still be able to use the nstoolbar.

thx in advance 
--molter

Comment: don't ever do that. if you're writing a kiosk-type application then follow the guidelines for writing kiosk-type applications.

Comment: what would you do instead? at the moment I have some kind of _remote_ to controll the window (start the streaming process; end it; etc) … I want to reduce the number of panels, windows and views of my app therfore I thought it might be nice to have toolbar to controll the window …

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the user to move the toolbar in that case? What if they wanted to move it to another space, or another screen? What if the screen resolution changes when the user moves their laptop to a new location?

Comment: This turns out to be relevant to me, two years later, due to Lion's fullscreen mode. I have a borderless window with a custom titlebar, similar to the App Store. However, in full screen mode, it could still be dragged around. arri's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

I would agree with Jason for 'normal' cases.
But i think that there are special situations where it can appropriate to do such thing.
Appearantly Apple also thinks so; starting with 10.6 - all you need to do is call NSWindows'

```
- (void)setMovable:(BOOL)flag
```

or override

```
- (BOOL)isMovable;
```

in your NSWindow-subclass to change the windows' movability.

If this is not available, the Quartz Event Services API ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)) provides ways to prevent the window from being moved.
One way would be to install an event-tap and manipulate incoming events to only contain the initial mousedown location instead of the updated (real) location, when the user starts dragging the window.

Comment: good persepective on the issue.. do you think the new lion window resize api's could work as an alternative to the crunchy old quartz event handlers… say if one wanted to constrict the movement of a widow to, say, only ONE axis of movement, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the Jason's advice and use the kiosk mode. See this [technical note](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) on it.